# Can't connect my spring-boot application running in docker container to cassandra container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, docker-compose

I tried pinging from spring-boot container to cassandra container,it's working fine.But while bringing up my apllication I am getting error like .

> NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried:
>   cassandra/172.21.0.3:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
>   [cassandra/172.21.0.3:9042] Cannot connect))

[image: Error image]

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - ./create_topic.sh:/create_topics.sh

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: "anonymous"

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.3.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  cassandra:
    image: ************/cassandra_goldendata_baseimage:1.0.0
    container_name: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"


  item-service:
    image: item-service
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - cassandra
    container_name: item-servicecontainer
    ports:
      - "4545:8080"
```

Comment: can you put your application.properties/yml file where cassandra configs are mentioned?

Comment: Can you also put the properties file your using for your connection to cassandra in spring boot application

Comment: Check the availability of cassandra by a `nodetool status` command. Also try to connect to cassandra via a cqlsh client.

Comment: When i tried to do cqlsh from my spring boot application i got like this -

Comment: cqlsh -u ukgrqe -p ukgrqe cassandra
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Comment: cqlsh -u ukgrqe -p ukgrqe 172.27.0.3
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")}) .                   @ note cassandra is my service name as mentioned in docker-compose and 172.27.0.3 is my cassandra container ip

Comment: after doing nodetool status i got .  root@1bd9057c3985:/# nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.0.3  282.91 KiB  256          100.0%            ef07c4cd-a052-4d68-8dc7-597d9b5576d2  rack1